# thunderbird address book not working after cleaning folder

Tags: email, thunderbird

Since my email is IMAP, I did [this](https://superuser.com/a/756442/511881) in order to free some space, but now my address book is not working anymore. I lost some entries and I cannot add anymore new contacts to it, launching thinderbird from the terminal, when I click to the star icon next to an email address to add it to the address book nothing happens and there is this error:

NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIAbDirectory.addCard]

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Uninstall, clean folders and reinstall TB, conserving address book.

Answer (score 0):

@rok, **please** [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Thunderbird).
Thanks.